# Enumerating data-targets in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an accordion in my HTML that is dynamically populated as such -

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-panel">
    <div class="accordion-heading>
      <a data-target="#collapse" data-toggle="collapse">{{x.header}}</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse" class="accordion-body"> 
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the `data-target` remains static. So all the open/close buttons only open one piece of the accordion! The solution would be to enumerate the `data-target`/`id`s based on `$index`, but I don't know how to do that.

Is there a way to enumerate attributes in the way that I described? Or is there another solution I can use?

Comment: may be simply #collapse-{{$index}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace `data-target` value with `#collepse-{{$index}}` and `ID` of body with `'collapse-{{$index}}'`

Hope this might be helpful to you!!

Comment: Ah, didnt realize you could use angular expressions in non-angular attributes. seems obvious now.